How to improve scalability of my optimization problem?
I am trying to optimize the number of store managers given different constraints.
Basically I want to minimize the number of managers that have to visit stores everyday in the week.
I designed the problem with Pulp library and found that it works for very small number of stores (until 10), but it won't scale for much more (e.g. 300 stores)
Some explanation about the use case:

Each store has to be visited once by week and by max 1 manager
Manager can work (including travel) up to 8 hours a day
If a manager visit a store, then he will be attributed a random "home" store he visits as if he was living there (simplification for travel time computation)

I didn't manage yet to implement the travel feature (for now I assume it takes 2 hours) but it should  actually account for the max time travel between stores visited the day and the "home" store. For the time travel between stores, I for now consider arbitrary value for the max hours worked per day (I know it is a TSP problem but I can't implement it directly so I will retrieve solutions and then later perform TSP on them to see if they are suitable).
I only have little knowledge in optimization, how do you think it could be optimized ? Or is it too complicated from the beginning and will take too much time to compute ?
import pulp as lp
import numpy as np

# Number of stores
num_stores = 11

# Generate a randomd time matrix (hours)
np.random.seed(42)  # Set seed for reproducibility
random_distances = np.random.uniform(1, 2, size=(num_stores, num_stores))

# Make the matrix symmetric by copying the upper triangle to the lower triangle
time_matrix = (random_distances + random_distances.T) / 2

# Set the diagonal to 0 (distance from a store to itself is zero)
np.fill_diagonal(time_matrix, 0)

# Convert the numpy matrix to a Python list (for use in PuLP)
time_matrix = time_matrix.tolist()

# Parameters
num_managers = 4 # Max number of area managers
num_days = 5  # Days in a week
working_hours_per_day = 8
service_time = 1  # Time spent at each store 

# Create a PuLP model
model = lp.LpProblem("StoreManagerAssignmentPerDay", lp.LpMinimize)

# Decision variables
# x[i, j, d] = 1 if store i is assigned to manager j on day d, otherwise 0
x = lp.LpVariable.dicts("x", ((i, j, d) for i in range(num_stores) for j in range(num_managers) for d in range(num_days)), cat=lp.LpBinary)

# z[i1, i2, j, d] = 1 if both stores i1 and i2 are assigned to manager j on day d
z = lp.LpVariable.dicts("z", ((i1, i2, j, d) for i1 in range(num_stores) for i2 in range(num_stores) 
                              for j in range(num_managers) for d in range(num_days)), cat=lp.LpBinary)

# New binary variables y[j] to indicate if manager j is used
y = lp.LpVariable.dicts("y", (j for j in range(num_managers)), cat=lp.LpBinary)

# Home store assignment variable
h = lp.LpVariable.dicts("h", ((i, j) for i in range(num_stores) for j in range(num_managers)), cat=lp.LpBinary)

# Objective: Minimize the number of managers used
model += lp.lpSum([y[j] for j in range(num_managers)])

# Constraints

#0. Set objective function
for j in range(num_managers):
    model += y[j] >= lp.lpSum([x[i, j, d] for i in range(num_stores) for d in range(num_days)])/(num_stores*num_days), f"Link_y_{j}"

# 1. Each store must be assigned to exactly one manager across all days
for i in range(num_stores):
    model += lp.lpSum([x[i, j, d] for j in range(num_managers) for d in range(num_days)]) == 1, f"AssignStore_{i}"

# 2. Linking constraints for z variables
for j in range(num_managers):
    for d in range(num_days):
        for i1 in range(num_stores):
            for i2 in range(i1 + 1, num_stores):
                # z[i1, i2, j, d] can only be 1 if both x[i1, j, d] and x[i2, j, d] are 1
                model += z[i1, i2, j, d] <= x[i1, j, d], f"Link_z_{i1}_{i2}_{j}_{d}_1"
                model += z[i1, i2, j, d] <= x[i2, j, d], f"Link_z_{i1}_{i2}_{j}_{d}_2"
                model += z[i1, i2, j, d] >= x[i1, j, d] + x[i2, j, d] - 1, f"Link_z_{i1}_{i2}_{j}_{d}_3"

# 3. Maximum working hours per day
for j in range(num_managers):
    for d in range(num_days):
        service_time_total = lp.lpSum([x[i, j, d] * service_time for i in range(num_stores)])
        travel_time_total = lp.lpSum([z[i1, i2, j, d] * time_matrix[i1][i2] 
                                      for i1 in range(num_stores) for i2 in range(i1 + 1, num_stores)])
        
        # Introduce a variable to represent the maximum travel time to the home store for each manager and day
        max_travel_to_home = lp.LpVariable(f"max_travel_to_home_{j}_{d}", lowBound=0)

        # Add constraints to ensure max_travel_to_home[j, d] captures the maximum travel time to home
        # for h_i in range(num_stores):
        #     # Add a constraint that captures the maximum travel time
        #     model += max_travel_to_home >= lp.lpSum([travel_time[i][h_i] * x[i, j, d] for i in range(num_stores)]) * h[h_i, j], f"MaxTravelToHome_{j}_{d}_{h_i}"

        # Total time for each manager per day includes service time, travel time, and the maximum travel time to the home store
        total_time = service_time_total + travel_time_total + 2
        model += total_time <= working_hours_per_day, f"MaxWorkingHours_{j}_{d}"

# 4. Home store assignment
for j in range(num_managers):
    # Linking visits to having a home store
    model += lp.lpSum([h[i, j] for i in range(num_stores)]) >= lp.lpSum([x[i, j, d] for i in range(num_stores) for d in range(num_days)])/num_stores, f"HomeStoreIfVisited_{j}"
    # Ensure no home store if no visits
    model += lp.lpSum([h[i, j] for i in range(num_stores)]) <= lp.lpSum([x[i, j, d] for i in range(num_stores) for d in range(num_days)]), f"NoVisitsNoHomeStore_{j}"
    # A manager cannot have more than one home store
    model += lp.lpSum([h[i, j] for i in range(num_stores)]) <= 1, f"OneHomeStorePerManager_{j}"


# 5. If a manager is assigned a home store, they must visit it during the week
for i in range(num_stores):
    for j in range(num_managers):
        model += h[i, j] <= lp.lpSum([x[i, j, d] for d in range(num_days)]), f"HomeStoreVisits_{i}_{j}"


solver = lp.PULP_CBC_CMD(msg=1)
model.solve(solver)

min_managers = int(lp.value(lp.lpSum([y[j] for j in range(num_managers)])))

print(f"Minimum number of managers required: {min_managers}")


A couple of things to help move this along:

It's a TSP with several twists, so it is not going to scale well, but it should do well over 10.

Your linking variable z is not implemented correctly, so your results are inaccurate.  Do a little side research on the linking variables for TSP.  Plenty online or in any LP textbook.  Not convinced?  add this after your solve:



for idx in z:
    print(idx, z[idx].varValue)


It isn't clear what the implication of days is.  If the traveler just picks up where they left off the day before (assumption), why bother with days and not just do 8 x 5 = 40hrs?

As you develop this, start with SMALL data and non-random values.  Something you can work out on a piece of scratch paper and make a formula that computes the travel time per manager from the .varValues after the solve and check it!  Start with 1 manager, 4 stores.  Convince yourself that it works and aligns with what your manual calculations.  Add a second manager and try minimizing travel time or such and convince yourself that works, go from there...  :)



Thank you for your answer.

Could you point out how uncorrect is it implemented so I can make the changes ?
The manager has to go back to its "home" store each day, does it prevent your 8 x 5 idea ?
Good idea I will check myself on very small data

Regarding the scaling, do you think it will work "easily" on 350 stores ? Because on &à it works in <10s and for 11 it never worked for me (you can easily reproduce)

Also I printed the idx, z[idx].varValue and it seemed to work. At least i get 1 when the pair of stores are visited, and if not it is 0 or None (not sure why it's not 0 though)
